# Why do ANSI escape codes sometimes work in CMD

Tags: python, cmd, rust, rust-cargo, ansi-escape

ANSI escape codes do not work by default in cmd.

But however some application do some kind of initialization after which they seem to seem to work during that session.

How do they do this initialization?
Here is an example -

I built a simple rust application that uses ANSI codes for colorful output.

[image: Image showing cargo using ANSI escape codes.]

However if I first build the project, then close that session and then again start cmd going to the directory in which my compiled project is and then run the executable (this time without using cargo at all in this session)-

[image: ANSI escape codes without cargo]

It seems like applications like cargo (and other applications also) do some kind of initialization step in the cmd after which the terminal seems to recognize ANSI codes.

And also in Python
Calling `os.system('')` before using ANSIescape codes does the job -

[image: ANSI escape codes work after os.system('')]

It seems like `os.system('')` is a bug, and you shoudn't rely on bugs to make your code work. Is there a better way to initialize ANSI escape codes in cmd?

Comment: `println!("\u{1b}[32;5;1mHello\u{1b}[0m, world!");` works fine for me without using Cargo. Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't realize you were talking about *Windows* cmd.exe. ANSI escape sequences should work in any ANSI terminal. Are you sure that rustc is using ANSI codes, or is it doing something platform-specific to give you colors on Windows?

Comment: I'd bet that cargo in windows pipes in the ANSI codes of your running program and translates them to colored output on-the-fly. Just guessing from the [source](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/0506d8d5c9dd229c94641dd39a37bd947dc0a770/src/cargo/core/shell.rs#L330). And if I'm right that gives you an easy solution for you problem: use the same crate Cargo-for-Windows does: [fwdansi](https://crates.io/crates/fwdansi).

Comment: I have added an example of what I am trying to say @trentcl .

Comment: You should look into how `colorama`, a python library, deals with this through its `init()` function: https://pypi.org/project/colorama/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're searching for is [`ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode). The reason it sometimes "stops working", is because some applications disable it before exiting. If it was already enabled, then this is when stuff breaks.

However, you can easily enable it (again) by calling [`SetConsoleMode()`](https://docs.rs/winapi/0.3.9/winapi/um/consoleapi/fn.SetConsoleMode.html) using the [`winapi` crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi). You can also use the [`winapi-util` crate](https://crates.io/crates/winapi-util) which makes it a bit easier.

```rust
#[cfg(windows)]
pub fn enable_virtual_terminal_processing() {
    use winapi_util::console::Console;

    if let Ok(mut term) = Console::stdout() {
        let _ = term.set_virtual_terminal_processing(true);
    }
    if let Ok(mut term) = Console::stderr() {
        let _ = term.set_virtual_terminal_processing(true);
    }
}
```

```
[target.'cfg(windows)'.dependencies]
winapi-util = "0.1"
```

To be *safe* you could call `enable_virtual_terminal_processing()` initially in `main()`. However, I definitely recommend calling it after executing a [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html), e.g.:

```rust
let output = Command::new("...")
    .args(&["..."])
    .output()
    .expect("failed to execute process");

#[cfg(windows)]
enable_virtual_terminal_processing();
```